# Go：How to print dog, cat and fish alternately for 3 times through 3 goroutine without deadlock？

Tags: go, goroutine

1.How to use sync.WaitGroup to solve deadlock？

My code can print the result correctly, but it will cause deadlock.

What I can think of now is:replace sync.WaitGroup with time.Sleep.

But I want to know how to use sync.WaitGroup to solve deadlock？

2. This is the result of the run：

```
dog: 0
cat: 0                                                           
fish: 0                                                          
dog: 1                                                           
cat: 1                                                           
fish: 1                                                          
dog: 2                                                           
cat: 2                                                           
fish: 2                                                          
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!               
                                                                 
goroutine 1 [semacquire]:                                        
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0xeaeeb0)                                
        D:/GoSDK/go1.17.3/src/runtime/sema.go:56 +0x25           
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x60)                                     
        D:/GoSDK/go1.17.3/src/sync/waitgroup.go:130 +0x71
```

3. This is my code：

```
func main(){
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(3)
    const Count = 3
    ch1, ch2, ch3 := make(chan bool), make(chan bool), make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            <-ch1
            fmt.Println("dog:", i)
            //notice 2
            ch2 <- true
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            //wait 1
            <-ch2
            fmt.Println("cat:", i)
            //notice 3
            ch3 <- true
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            //wait 2
            <-ch3
            fmt.Println("fish:", i)
            //notice 1
            ch1 <- true
        }
    }()
    //notic 1
    ch1 <- true
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: You should your [mutex](https://gobyexample.com/mutexes) to prevent from deadlock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that no go routine is waiting for `ch1`. So on the last iteration of the third goroutine locks (`ch1 <- true`).
So what you need is a way to recognize that the chain stopped.
My fast and humble suggestion:

```
func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(3)
    const Count = 3
    ch1, ch2, ch3 := make(chan bool), make(chan bool), make(chan bool)
    chainEnded := make(chan struct{})

    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            <-ch1
            fmt.Println("dog:", i)
            //notice 2
            ch2 <- true
        }
        chainEnded <- struct{}{}
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            //wait 1
            <-ch2
            fmt.Println("cat:", i)
            //notice 3
            ch3 <- true
        }
    }()
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < Count; i++ {
            //wait 2
            <-ch3
            fmt.Println("fish:", i)
            //notice 1
            ch1 <- true
        }
    }()
    //notic 1
    ch1 <- true
    <-chainEnded // wait for the loop to end and send to this chan
    <-ch1        // unblock the attempt to chain of the last routine
    wg.Wait()
}
```